# Display jQuery dialog from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have researched this for days! I'm simply trying to get an event in VB code behind to display a jQuery dialog (with suitable message).

My (very simple) HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ButtonMustWork.aspx.vb" Inherits="NowDisplayPictures.ButtonMustWork" %>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>

    function GetDialogBox() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
            <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />   
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my VB button on-click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Test", "<script>GetDialog();</script>")
End Sub
```

All I get is a blank page with the  text on it, and a button .Any ideas please?

Comment: but it will hide after postback. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I agree - this is what it looks likt it is doing, but I want it to display obviously! Can you tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is `GetDialogBox();` but you are calling `GetDialog();` in your code.